# C Gnu makefile I cannot make a static library with ar

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, g++, gnu

When I try this;

```
VPATH= ./src
CXXFLAGS=   -I  "./include"
program: ListNode.o LinkedList.o TreeNode.o Tree.o Test.o
    g++ lib\ListNode.o  lib\LinkedList.o    lib\TreeNode.o  lib\Tree.o  lib\Test.o  -o  bin\program
ListNode.o: ListNode.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\ListNode.o
LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\LinkedList.o
TreeNode.o: TreeNode.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\TreeNode.o
Tree.o: Tree.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\Tree.o
Test.o: Test.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\Test.o
clean:
    del *.exe
    del *.o
```

It all works without any problem.But for my homework I have to create a static library.Anyway when I add this command to the makefile;

```
VPATH= ./src
CXXFLAGS=   -I  "./include"
program: ListNode.o LinkedList.o TreeNode.o Tree.o Test.o
    g++ lib\ListNode.o  lib\LinkedList.o    lib\TreeNode.o  lib\Tree.o  lib\Test.o  -o  bin\program
ListNode.o: ListNode.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\ListNode.o
LinkedList.o: LinkedList.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\LinkedList.o
TreeNode.o: TreeNode.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\TreeNode.o
Tree.o: Tree.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\Tree.o
Test.o: Test.cpp
    g++ -c  $(CXXFLAGS) $<  -o  lib\Test.o
clean:
    del *.exe
    del *.o
libclass.a: ListNode.o  LinkedList.o
    ar -rcs libclass.a lib\ListNode.o lib\LinkedList.o
```

It doesn't do anything.There is no file or there is no error.Its like it doesn't exist :/

By the way I think it'd be good to mention about that if I use first makefile and then I put this code on terminal;

```
ar -rcs libclass.a lib\*.o
```

It works like magic i mean perfectly.So I need a little bit help cuz I'm about to go insane.Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you invoking make? My make may be a little rusty, but since `program` does not depend on your lib, `make program` doesn't need to build it.

Comment: Side note: You're breaking rules 2 and 4 of the [Rules of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/), all of your rules will run each time which completely defeats the purpose of make.

Comment: Yes it doesn't depend on my lib.I didn't intend to do that because I was trying to run ar command in makefile.But eventually its gonna be
#program: libclass.a Test.o #  or something like that. -@melak47

Comment: Can you be more specific about details? I checked the link that you shared.But I am a newbie about makefile.If you have a time to show the rules on my code I will be greatful. @user657267

Comment: It's not that tricky, as an example consider your rule for `program`. This rule doesn't create `program` it creates `bin/program`, so make that the target. Its prerequisites are given as `ListNode.o` etc, but those aren't the prerequisites, which are `lib/ListNode.o` etc. Make is useful because it allows you to perform minimal recompilations, but only if your rules are written correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
all: program libclass.a
```

to the beginning of your makefile. By default, `make` builds only the first target it finds in your makefile. This declares a fake target named "all" that depends on "program" and "libclass.a", so `make` ends up building both.